# Cloud Firestore splitting access levels for extra sensitive user data

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I want to restrict access to sensitive attributes of my `Users` documents to a smaller set of clients. My current understanding is that there are two ways to split the data, so that we can make security rules for each part:

1. Create a `Users` collection and a top level `SensitiveUserData` collection that both use the same document ID, and only retrieve the `SensitiveUserData` for a user when needed and allowed.
2. Create a `SensitiveUserData` subcollection within the `User` document. This collection will always contain just a single document, but the ID won't matter.

Which of these (or a third) is preferred in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of these approaches is pertinently better than the other, and both have valid use-cases. In the end it's a combination of personal preference, and a (typically evolving) insight into the use-cases of your app.

In many scenarios, using subcollections is preferred as it allows the data to be better spread out over the physical storage, which in turn helps throughput. But in this case I doubt that makes a difference, as you're likely to use the user ID as keys in both `SensitiveUserData` and `Users` collections, so they'll be similarly distributed anyway.

For me personally, I often end up with a top-level collection. But that may well be related to my long history of modeling data in the Firebase Realtime Database, where access permission is inherited, so you can't hide a subcollection there.